Native query executing returning java.lang.Character instead of "" string after spring boot 3 migration
We recently migrated our spring boot application from spring boot 2.7 to 3.2. After migration, we noticed that some of native sql query executions were giving java.lang.Character datatype instead of an "" string.
Native query example:
 Select...    ,  '' as data, ....

The data field should have been a  "" string after native query executions but in spring boot 3, it's being returned as a java.lang.Character object  which is breaking our application.
I know that in spring boot 3, javax.persistence.* has been migrated to jakarta.persistence.* but didn't find any relevant breaking changes for my use-case.
Code for native query execution:
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Object[]> executeNativeQuery(String sql) {
   return this.em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
}

    

